# Too many DML Statements 151 when executing flow

Tags: soql, flow, visual-flows

I have created a flow that looks up for opportunity object and then performs certain modification.

******The flow works fine in the sandbox however when I run the same flow in production. I get "Too many DML Statements 151".******

The issue seems to be Data dependent on the number of opportunity records being modified.

I searched for this and found that we can avoid this error in code by modifying the code to reduce the number of DML statements.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000093BAIAY  https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004825&language=en_US 
[Too many DML statements: 151 - no DML in a for loop (that I can see)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/67136/too-many-dml-statements-151-no-dml-in-a-for-loop-that-i-can-see)

Any suggestions on how to handle this in a flow would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code/flow?

Comment: as far as I guess -- you are looping on records, and doing DML every single record. Try to add records to collection and perform single DML

Comment: I tried to bulkify the flow and used fast update and that resolved the issue. Thank you all for the help!